# Select Distinct Value from Multiple tables, Where One has Multiples

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have searched for this problem but have not found anything quite like it.  I have two tables, both with a field, FormID.  In table A, FormID is unique.  In table B, there can be multiple records with the same FormID -- table B is a problem tracker table, so if there are multiple data entry problems in the form, there will be multiple records in there.

The following query works:

```
select distinct b.FormID
from b
where b.FormID = a.FormID
and a.status='done'
```

as far it does generate a result list of unique FormIDs.  However, I also need to get some other columns in this query and it's when I add those columns to the select or the join that I get ALL the duplicate FormIDs.

I have tried:

```
select distinct (b.FormID), a.FormType, a.Site, a.uid, b.ProbID, b.Date
from b, a
where b.FormID = a.FormID
and a.status='done'
```

as well as a couple of variations using joins, but they all end up with all the rows with duplicate FormIDs.

Suggestions?

Comment: So, assuming that you will have different values for `b.ProbID` and `b.Date`, which of one of these values would you want to show... since there is a one-to-many relationship between `a` and `b`.

Comment: Which dbms? PostgreSQL has a nice version to do it but others require a bit of work.

Comment: Ooops, sorry, it's MS SQL 2008.  And, I don't really care which record in B I get, the main thing is that I need a list of all FormIDs that have a data entry problem.  Then, I will display those forms for someone to manually fix, but I don't want multiples of the same form in that list.

Comment: Ok, well, your comment pointed out my problem. I don't really need to query for the values in B, other than the FormID.  I just tried that and it worked.  Thanks and sorry to bother!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT  b.FormID, 
        MAX(a.FormType) FormType, 
        MAX(a.Site) Site, 
        MAX(a.uid) uid, 
        MAX(b.ProbID) ProbID, 
        MAX(b.Date) Date
  FROM b INNER JOIN 
       a ON b.FormID = a.FormID
 WHERE a.status='done'
 GROUP BY b.FormID
```